# Keeping grep output in a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I am coding a shell script, where I want to get file last 24 hour file changes of a directory. I am doing it like below:

```
for myfile in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1)
    do
        echo $myfile|sed 's/.//'| sed 's/.//'|grep -v "^$";
    done
```

So, now I want to keep the output of `$myfile|sed 's/.//'| sed 's/.//'|grep -v "^$";` in a shell variable and want to pass to another bash function. I tried it like below:

```
   for myfile in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1)
        do
            latest_file=$($myfile|sed 's/.//'| sed 's/.//'|grep -v "^$");
        done
```

And I getting `bash: .: filename argument required` error.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed `echo` when adding the `$(...)`.#!/usr/bin/perl

```
latest_file=$(echo $myfile | sed 's/..//' | grep -v "^$")
#             ~~~~
```

Also note that `sed 's/.//' | sed 's/.//'` is equivalent to `sed 's/..//` which is faster. You can also try `cut -c3-` (i.e. show each line from the third character).

Comment: Hmm didn't think about that! echo is for printing staff STDOUT thats why I did not keep it when assigning a variable.

Comment: @AlexBenz: Here STDOUT goes through `|` to the STDIN of `sed`.